# How to check for Publisher and Subscriber in transactional replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

In transactional replication, at a particular point of time how can i check and confirm whether data at Publisher and Subscriber is same?
I don't want to check latency/trace token - as latency will only tell how much subscriber is behind from Publisher/distributor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a data validation to see how out of sync you are.  Details on validating data can be found in [Validate Replicated Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152758.aspx).

You can also use the [tablediff utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx) or SQL Data Compare to see how out of sync you are and generate a T-SQL script to bring the data back into convergence.